Microsoft SQL Server Usage Data
I want to build a usage scanner for SQL Server to gather information about which user performed which query, how much time it took, etc., similar to Snowflake.
In Snowflake, there's the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY table, and in Teradata, we have DBQ queries. I used system tables like sys.dm_exec_requests, sys.dm_exec_query_stats, and sys.dm_exec_sessions, but they only provide data for the current day.
My question is how can I get this type of information to get usage level information?
I cannot see audit table in which I have this type of information.
Help is really appreciated.

You'd have to create either extended event session or an audit to track executions, if that's what you're looking for
